# BDC: Decimal field with comma separator

Tags: bdc

Sorry for my English. I'm in despair.

I created external content type from table. I created external list.
Decimal field with comma ( thousand separator ) from external list saved wrong to data base.

In list view we see 11,00000. In edit form too. But after save ( open and save without edit ) in list view ( and on all forms too ) we see 1100000,00000.

Type of column in data base is decimal(12,5).

Locate (Site setting -> Regional Setting ): Russian.

Decimal symbol (System setting: Date and Time -> Region -> Customize Format ): comma.

What's wrong with BDC?

Comment: In list view and forms the decimal field displaying correctly ( with the comma sepparator ).

Comment: I have not formula in that column.

Comment: I try changed the regional settings to "English (United States)". It works fine cause the separator is period. But I need the "Russian" regional settings and the comma separator. I think BDC parse wrong decimal field with the comma separator ( cause ignored the comma separator ) and saved to data base wrong.

Comment: I think BDC is working from another the regionl setting.